# Wrong layout for UIActionSheet with single destructive button

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

In my application I am using an action sheet to confirm deletions, similar to the built-in Photos app. On the iPad, the action sheet shows only the destructive button; it is cancelled by tapping outside the popover showing the action sheet.

When I show the action sheet, then the popover showing the action sheet is too high - the destructive button has some padding below:

[image: Action sheet with popover larger than the single button]

This is different from the behavior of the Photos app, where the popover is exactly as large as the destructive button:

[image: Action sheet with popover in the Photos app]

Is there a way to have the height of the action sheet similar to the Pictures app?

I am using Xamarin for development, I am using this code to show the action sheet:

```
actionSheet = new UIActionSheet(null, null, null, "Delete Attachment");
actionSheet.ShowFrom(NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem, true);
```

The Objective C equivalent for this code is:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
  delegate:nil
  cancelButtonTitle:nil
  destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete Attachment"
  otherButtonTitles:nil];
[actionSheet showFromBarButtonItem: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
  animated: YES];
```

Comment: @mehulpatel No, I did not. As the popover and its view are handled by the UIActionSheet, I see no way where I could pass contentSizeForViewInPopover to it (not to mention that this is deprecated in iOS 7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior occurs if `cancelButtonTitle` is `nil` (`null`). If I specify a string as the cancelButtonTitle, the iPad UI won't show the cancel button, but show the button with the correct layout.

Got the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20907552/112964 for the question [Remove Padding from UIActionSheet Popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907395/remove-padding-from-uiactionsheet-popover).